# Youtube iframe, z-index, Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I'm doing some fixes on a website.

There's a youtube iframe on top, which is supposed to have a 940px widthto overlay part of the menu on the right side.iframe has a z-index of 1000.
Chrome and IE display everything properly, But not firefox.

No, it isn't a duplicate question, I have tried adding wmode=opaque, wmode=transparent, with the correct ?/& , as param, and with the jquery fix that adds it to all the iframes (you'll know what im talking about if you google the issue). Hell, I even forced html5 video, and it tdidn't change a thing.

So maybe I'm just stupid and missing something... But it doesn't work! If you need me to post more info, I'll happily do it, my head is gonna explode.

G.

Comment: Omg... I definitely knew that :D Thanks, man. Make it an answer and get the points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `position:` value on the iframe if you want to use `z-index`, like `position:relative;` or `position:absolute;`